# Is there a function to print JSON schema in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I read in the JSON file as Pandas data frame. Now I want to print the JSON object schema. I look around and mostly I only saw links to do this online but my file is too big (almost 11k objects/lines). I'm new at this so I was wondering is there a function/code that I can do this in python?

What I have so far...

```
import json

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('/Users/name/Downloads/file.json', lines = True)

print(df)
```

Comment: if by schema you mean the keys in the json, wouldn't that just be the column names?

Comment: @ArthurBorshenko Hello, isn't schema is both the column names and their structure but in the JSON format?

Comment: It would be great if you provided what an example output should look like.

Comment: @ArthurBorshenko I don't have an example, it's just that when I looked up JSON schema, I noticed that they tend to look like this (https://blog.runscope.com/posts/validate-your-apis-against-json-schema-using-runscope) but I'm not sure if this is how it's supposed to be...

Comment: copy your json content, and pasted to a json format web, and it will give you a good-look format to explore, e.g. https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html  `import json`
`print(json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))`

Comment: it's unclear what response you're expecting. For example, a pydantic schema? A Python schema? A dataclass schema? Or perhaps just pretty print the json .e.g via `json.dumps(o, indent=2)` ?

Comment: @rv.kvetch Or a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)…

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but, maybe if you try to convert the df into json inside a variable and then print the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can if you use the pydantic and datamodel-code-generator libraries.

Use datamodel-code-generator to produce the Python model and then use pydantic to print out the schema from the model.